# SSIS data viewer does not show the rows count and the data

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to see the rows count in the Data Flow path. I already folowed this instructions (https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/debugging-data-flow-in-sql-server-integration-services/) but the number of rows between the steps and the pop-up with the data are not appearing.

Can anybody help me?

thanks

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Is your package finishing when you execute it?

Comment: Are you sure that your source query returns rows? What you describe is - as far as I know - the standard behaviour when no rows are fetched by the source.

Comment: No there are no erros.
Yes, there are a lot of data rows in my flow.
I think is bug on the Visual Studio. I tryed to reinstall the Data Tools component, but not works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with SSDT in Visual Studio 2017 using the Dark theme. The foreground font color of the row counts matched the background canvas color so the counts were not visible. I changed the theme to the out-of-the-box Light theme and the counts became visible.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is like mine, the number of rows IS there, but the font for it is simply the same as the background. This was a very tough error to spot. I think this could be a bug when you use SSDT alone and not the full install of Visual Studio, as I currently do.

What worked for me is downloading the VS2017 (or whatever version you are on) Color Theme from here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor

I changed mine to Purple and it worked. Maybe other themes will work as well. Good luck!

Comment: The link in this answer appears to be broken. Apparently the new URL is https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor